# SUM of a column using WHERE clause in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to use multiple Count and Sum commands in a single query.
However what is happening is when i use the following:

`SUM(amount AND type = "dispute") as charge`

It actually counts the amount of records and does not total the amounts.
What i want to do is use SUM with a where clause multiple times, so for example:

```
`$query = DB::table('cash_table')
        ->where('transaction_created', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfWeek())
        ->select(DB::raw('
            SUM(amount) as transaction_amount,
            COUNT(amount) as transaction_count,
            SUM(amount) WHERE type = "dispute" as charge_amount
            COUNT(amount) WHERE type = "dispute" as charge_count
            SUM(loan_amount) WHERE type = "loan" as loan_amount
            COUNT(loan_amount) WHERE type = "loan" as loan_count
            '))
        ->groupBy('transaction_created')
        ->get();`
```

The top two "transaction_amount & transaction count work fine as there is no where clause" The other don't.

Comment: pass multiple `DB::raw` statements inside of select as array `->select([DB:raw(),DB::raw(),DB::raw()])`

Comment: Is it possible to provide an example for me please

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi, please help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below!

```
$query = DB::table('cash_table')
            ->where('transaction_created', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfWeek())->select(
                DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN type = "dispute" THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as charge'),
                DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN type = "refund" THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as refund'),
                DB::raw('COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "approved" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as transaction_count'),
                DB::raw('SUM(amount) as transaction_amount')
            )
            ->groupBy('transaction_created')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
$query = DB::table('cash_table')
    ->where('transaction_created', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfWeek())
    ->select(DB::raw('
            SUM(amount) as transaction_amount,
            COUNT(amount) as transaction_count,
            SUM(if(type = "dispute", amount, 0)) as charge_amount
            COUNT(type = "dispute") as charge_count
            SUM(if(type = "loan", amount, 0)) as loan_amount
            COUNT(type = "loan")as loan_count
            '))
    ->groupBy('transaction_created')
    ->get();
```

Comment: that did not work, does not display correct data